# Does a handlebars.js implementation in java exist?

Tags: java, javascript, templating, mustache, handlebars.js

Currently I'm using Mustache templates ( http://mustache.github.com/ ) both on the client and server-side, using javascript and java implementation respectively.

However, there are some limitations in Mustache which the relatively new Handlebars.js ( http://www.handlebarsjs.com/ ) tries to overcome.

However as far as I see it handlebars only has a javascript implementation as of yet. 
Anyone knows of an (experimental) java-implementation of Handlebars?

Comment: I have no idea why this question was closed. I don't know how this question could "solicit debate, arguments, polling". There is not exactly many handlebars libraries out there and this post is the only way to currently find the only one especially since Edgar Espina renamed his github account to jknack.

Comment: I agree there is no way this question should have been closed. The answers have been very useful to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just saw this one pop up : 
https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java
which was originally here:
https://github.com/edgarespina/handlebars.java (update your maven dependencies as the projects group id has changed also).

I have not tested it yet.

Comment: https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen a Java implementation of handlebars as yet. Handlebars was [originally developed](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/09/09/announcing-handlebars-js/) by [Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/), predominantly a Ruby and JavaScript developer hence the JavaScript and Ruby implementations of it. Handlebars is an extension of the mustache syntax and thus not part of the mustache standard.

Comment: I knew how Handlebars came into existence, thanks. I'll keep this question open for a while, to see if anything new pops on the radar.

Answer (score 2):

In theory handlebars could be compatible with rhino. Our team uses rhino in our java stack to compile less css files on the server. This person looks to have added rhino support to handlebars:

https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/49

although it has not been pull into the repo yet.

Answer (score 2):

Handlebars works well with Rhino on the simplest template example :)

https://github.com/MathieuLorber/Handlebars.js-Rhino-test

I haven't gone further for the moment...